# Does the .git folder update on each pull

Tags: php, git

I have an application that doesn't have any client side cache invalidation yet.

We need a quick solution for a temporary measure until we devise a fuller solution.

The prod server tracks the master branch.

Is it safe to assume the .git folder will update its last modified time-stamp upon every git pull?

If so a quick solution would be to set the last modified timestamp of the .git folder to be the js and css cache key... ie

```
<script src="<?= asset('build/js/main.js') ?>?v=<? echo $timestamp; ?>"></script>
```

Comment: Default git behaviour is updating the modification time every time it changes a file. so that is correct. I would not however rely on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assume that but i would not count on that.

A better way is to use the fetch command

```
git fetch --all --prune
```

Which will update the `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file stamp and you can use this instead.